# XQuery combining arrays

Tags: arrays, xquery, exist-db

I have three arrays:

```
let $a := [1,2,3] 
let $b := [4,5,6] 
let $c := [7,8,9]
```

I need to get the array:

```
[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7, 8, 9 ]
```

i.e. an array containing two arrays, and three integers.

I've tried virtually every variety of array:append, array:join etc., but these either end up not working (passing an array as an argument seems not to arbitrarily be treated as multiple arguments sometimes, not others) or flattening the first two arrays...

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Using `array { $a, $b, $c?* }` should do:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'adaptive';

let $a := [1,2,3] 
let $b := [4,5,6] 
let $c := [7,8,9]
return array { $a, $b, $c?* }
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhs